# Set required POST/GET parameters before accessing a functions

Tags: php

Is there any way or any plugin that starting from like a JSON definition will validate POST/GET parameters before accessing a function?

The JSON structure would be like this

```
{
    "function_name": "test_function",
    "post_params": ["color"]
    "get_params": []
}
```

We would need this to prevent adding the checks on every function (500+) as will need too much time

Thank you

Comment: You are useing some framework?

Comment: Yes, we are using Drupal

Comment: you can see if drupal does have a mechanism to apply custom function to all get / post request (in laravel there are the middlewares)